# Trouble iterating through properties of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
allRows[rowDiv.toString()] = rowDiv;
console.log('commence row' + allRows[rowDiv.toString()].phrases);
//not null
for(row in allRows) {
   console.log('for commence ' + row.phrases);
   //null
   console.log(row)
   //prints toString
}
```

rowDiv is an object with a property 'phrases'(which I defined in its constructor as this.phrases = [] and later added elements to).  allRows is an object containing all rowDiv objects (objects inserted through allRows[rowDiv.toString()] = rowDiv).  Why does 'row' just give me the toString and not the actual object?  Or it's possible something else is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just printing out the *key* of the object you are looking for.

In the dictionary you are using, you are using the result of `toString()` as a key.

To get the actual object, not just the `toString()` result, you need to use `allRows[row]` instead of just `row`.

So, for instance, with this change made your code would look like:

```
allRows[rowDiv.toString()] = rowDiv;
console.log('commence row' + allRows[rowDiv.toString()].phrases);
//not null
for(row in allRows) {
   console.log('for commence ' + row.phrases);
   //null
   console.log(allRows[row]); // CHANGE MADE HERE
   //prints toString
}
```

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer or the other one by clicking on the checkmark below the vote count.

Answer (score 2):

this type of "for each" loop in javascript works a bit differently. You have to do something like this:

```
for(row in allRows) {
   console.log('for commence ' + allRows[row].phrases);
   //null
   console.log(allRows[row])
   //no longer should print toString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also can be done using `for...of` 
https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

```
allRows[rowDiv.toString()] = rowDiv;
console.log('commence row' + allRows[rowDiv.toString()].phrases);
//not null
for(row of allRows) {
   console.log('for commence ' + row.phrases);
   //null
   console.log(row)
   //prints toString
}
```